# Is it possible to call the << operator using prefix notation?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, prefix-notation

I am wondering if I could write, for instance: `<<(object, cout);` or `<<(cout,object);` where object is a user defined class which has the `<<` operator overloaded, just as one could write:
`int a = +(2,3);` and obtain the expected result, as in `int a = 2 + 3;`.
 Furthermore, what should one do if this is possible, but requires a few steps? Should one overload the `<<` operator with two different signatures?

Comment: That's just function notation, you can't name a function `<<`.

Answer (score 2):

> just as one could write: int a = +(2,3); and obtain the expected
>   result, as in int a = 2 + 3;

No, you have a misunderstanding. `+(2, 3)` will go by the associativity of the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) and assign `+3` (3) to the variable `a`.

Therefore, `int a = +(2, 3)` is the same as `int a = 3`, and not `int a = 2 + 3`

> I am wondering if I could write, for instance: <<(object, cout); or
>   <<(cout,object);

No, you can't.

If you want to use the operators in that fashion then you should call its fully qualified name, for example:

`operator+` instead of `+`

`operator<<` instead of `<<`

*Note:*

This will not work for fundamental datatypes. Take care of the class scope and namespaces when you are using the overloaded versions of these operators.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Could you expand more on what is happening when writing `a = +(2, 3);` ?

Comment: @M.Ioan I have added a link

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, e.g.

```
operator<<(std::cout, "hi");
```

This expression

```
int a = +(2, 3);
```

is not doing `operator+`. It's first applying the `,` sequence operator, which gives `3`, and then applying unary `+`, which gives 3.

You can't do this

```
int a = operator+(2, 3); // error
```

because `int`s are fundamental types.

If you have user defined types `S`, then the following snippets have the same meaning

```
S s{};
std::cout << s;
auto x = s + s;
```

is the same as

```
S s{};
operator<<(std::cout, s);
auto x = operator+(s, s);
```

assuming the operators are defined for `S`, the correct operator will be called.

Comment: Thank you a lot! What if we weren't dealing with fundamental types?

Comment: @M.Ioan Added an explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that. This `operator<<(cout, "hi")` does compile and print "hi" though.

Comment: @cigien -- yup, I just tried it. Not sure why. But `operator<<(std::cout, 3)` doesn't work.

Comment: @PeteBecker yeah, and neither does `operator<<(std::cout, int{3})` either, so it's a different explanation. Seems ambiguous for some reason.

Comment: @PeteBecker `3` is of a fundamental datatype whereas `std::string` is not

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment; it came from a misreading of the documentation. Nevertheless: there are a handful of types for which the stream inserter is a member of `std::ostream`, and for those types, `operator<<(std::cout, value)` won't work, but `std::cout.operator<<(value)` will. The most interesting types where this applies are the numeric types.

Comment: @PeteBecker ok, so that's where the ambiguity comes from for `int`. I'm keeping the answer unchanged then.

Comment: @ArdentCoder -- it's not a matter of fundamental types. It's the somewhat arbitrary requirement that stream inserters for **numeric** types (and a few others) are defined inside `basic_ostream`. You have to look at the list; it's not a trivial classification.

Comment: @PeteBecker I know, but I was taught that simple memorization trick instead of learning the whole list :P

Comment: @PeteBecker I recommend you learn that trick lol. For serious purposes, refer the documentation.